# Backbone.js Router doesn't load initial request when there's a delay

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-routing

So in my script, I do the standard

```
var router = new App.MyRouter();
Backbone.history.start( { pushState: true } );
```

And that works fine. However, I'd like to have a the jQuery document ready block wrap around this. When that happens, the request doesn't trigger the routing.

I dug deeper and saw that whenever there's a delay, the request doesn't route. When I set a Timeout around the router, it won't work either. I've seen examples of it working for others, and don't see why it wouldn't work...this worries me because it suggests that there is a time in which the router can work and if there's any lag it won't...?

Comment: Router wrapped in document.ready() is working for me. Something is probably wrong with your script / the structure of your script. Could you post more from your code?

Comment: Ahh figured it out. Had to pass in the Backbone object.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the Backbone object in the function was different, so I had to pass it in.